# Windows Phone Dev Center Submit Error

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm getting the following error when submitting my app in the Windows Phone Dev Center:

> Couldn't save changes. We couldn't save the updated info at this time. Try again later. If you continue to get this message, contact support and provide the following ID:  and specify current DateTime in UTC: .

This worked on the weekend and the submission passed but I found a few bugs that I wanted to fix before going public, so I cancelled the release and tried to upload a new one.

So far I've tried deleting the submission and creating a new one, renaming the upload file to make it shorter and even re-submitting the build that passed the first time. All attempts still failed.

Any assistance or suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Did you try contacting the support with the issue?

Comment: Yes, I'm working with support at Microsoft but they are SLOOOWWW!!!

Comment: Microsoft engineering "tweaked" something and now it is working. Hope it stays that way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the only recourse is support. Microsoft engineering "tweaked" something and now it is working. If you run into this, use the support link http://dev.windows.com/en-us/community/support.